# Dealing with clicks from ActionItems in a QuickAction Dialog

Tags: android

I have a QuickAction dialog [like this](http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/) and would like instead of dealing with each ActionItem click with anonymous listeners

`final ActionItem chart = new ActionItem();

chart.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

@Override

public void onClick(View v) {

Toast.makeText(TestQuickAction.this, "Chart selected" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}

});`

I want to have just 1 onClick method in my class (to deal with all ActionItems) by implementing OnClickListener and onClick(View v).

`myclass implements View.OnClickListener{


public void onClick(View v){

//detect which ActionItem caused onClick...

}

}`

The problem is that even though selecting one of these ActionItems invokes onClick, an ActionItem isn't a View, it doesn't extend anything. How can I tell which ActionItem caused the click?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the `LinearLayout` container is the view, so by setting a tag on this container with a corresponding ActionItem's text (such as the title), and retrieving this tag using `view.getTag()` in `onClick()`, you should be able to uniquely identify which ActionItem caused the click.